# Are there infinite triplets that satisfy a! = b!⋅c! where a ≠ b+1?

Tags: factorial

I'm not a mathematician. I was recently watching a YT math question on what is 10! ÷ 6! = x!. It got me thinking, are there infinite triplets (a, b, c) that satisfy a!= b!⋅c!?

I wrote a short python program and found that there are many sets with (a+1, a, b) and you can construct them from (6, 5, 3) set onwards. Next set is (24 *(6⋅4)*, 23, 4), the next set is (120 *(24⋅5)*, 119, 6) and next is (720 *(6⋅120)*, 719, 7), and so on. I think it is explained [in this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907022/is-there-a-solution-to-a-b-cdot-c-cdot-d-cdot-e). This is I think what mathematician would call trivial solutions.

In the mix I also found one interesting set (10,7,6). While is kind of similar with b = c + 1, it is still different from rest. And in the small program I wrote and with the resources I had, I could only find 1 such set below 1000.  My question is, are there other such sets and are they infinitely many?

I tried google search but I think I'm not wording it properly that it brings. Would appreciate your inputs in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What does YT mean?

Comment: I meant YT - youtube,

Comment: You may wish to distinguish between the word "infinite" and the phrase "infinitely many", which usually have distinct meanings.